# How to transfer files between linux machines using xfb?

Tags: shell, unix

I need to write a script which transfers files from one server to another using XFB protocol. I googled about this and foung the below Info.

```
ConfigFile
---
nodeRemote=xx.UNIX.Axxxxxx
name=cdadmin
fromfile=xfb_bs_test.csv
runlocal=dummy
runremote=dummy
filetype=csv
tofile=xfb_bs_test.csv 


XFB cmd ::
btoput -f  ConfigFile
```

From the above i came to know that a ConfigFile need to  be passed as an argument to btoput.
But i am not knowing the exact significance of nodeRemote,name,fromfile,runlocal,runremote,tofile in the above ConfigFile.
Could someone please help me on this?

Comment: why not use `ssh` || `ftp`?

Comment: No. using ssh,sftp or ftp this can be done easily. But the requirement is to use XFB only.

Answer (score 1):

Details of the file goes as below;

```
nodeRemote=xx.UNIX.Axxxxxx <-- Remote Node to which File Trasnfer is being made. This can be looked up from locpart.smp
name=cdadmin <-- user with which file transfer is being made
fromfile=xfb_bs_test.csv <-- File being transferred
runlocal=dummy <-- Local Script to be executed post successful File transfer
runremote=dummy <-- Some Remote Script to be executed post successful File transfer [Generally used for Remote File processing]
filetype=csv <-- Type of File being transferred
tofile=xfb_bs_test.csv  <-- File name to be made at destination
```

Answer (score 0):

noderemote stands for your destination server XFB.ID
name stands for the linux user of the server which owns the XFB process.
fromfile stands for the source file name.(file location will be declared in a seperate config file)
runlocal and runremote stands for the scripts to be run on local(your machine) and remote(destination machine)